# How can I make this while loop faster on a microcontroller button?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am working with a micro controller that has a button A. When I press this button and hold it for 2 seconds, its value becomes 0 and the color turns either blue or green, when I release, its value goes back to 1 but the color stays the same unless it was clicked again and the color changes. The problem is, it shouldn't take someone 2 whole seconds to have to change the led light. What can I do to make the value (either 0 or 1) be read faster?

Here is a snippet of the code in the while loop.

```
// here are the states for reference. Everything is either a 0 or a 1
const int BUTTON_PRESSED = 0;
const int BUTTON_UNPRESSED = 1;

const int GREEN_LED = 0;
const int BLUE_LED = 1;

    const struct timespec sleepTime = { 1, 0 };

    while (true) {
        Value_Type value;
        // this function get the input of button a when pressed
        GetValue(button_A_fd, &value);
        Log_Debug(
           "Button value (%d)\n", value);

        // Processing the button.

        //Turns LED ON; Button not pressed down
        if (value == BUTTON_UNPRESSED) {
            last_button_state = BUTTON_UNPRESSED;
        } else {

            // if last button state is 1 then now it is being pressed
            if (last_button_state == BUTTON_UNPRESSED) {
                // Flip LEDs
                if (active_led == BLUE_LED) {
                    active_led = GREEN_LED;
                }
                else if (active_led == GREEN_LED) {
                    active_led = BLUE_LED;
                }

                last_button_state = BUTTON_PRESSED;
                // sets the pointer to the 0 bit of the file to write
                lseek(fd_storage, 0, SEEK_SET);
                // write current active led to mutable storage and save
                write(fd_storage, &active_led, sizeof(active_led));
            }
        }
        // Blinking the active LED.
        // reading input only when pressed and turn off other led
        if (active_led == GREEN_LED) {
            // turn off blue led, then turn on green
            SetValue(blue_led_fd, Value_High);
            SetValue(green_led_fd, Value_Low);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
            SetValue(green_led_fd, Value_High);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        }
        else if (active_led == BLUE_LED) {
            // turn off green led, then turn on blue
            SetValue(green_led_fd, Value_High);
            SetValue(blue_led_fd, Value_Low);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
            SetValue(blue_led_fd, Value_High);
            nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put GetValue() in several parts of the code to see if it could maybe get a value faster but it did not work. How can I move from here? I hope I shared enough code to understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I will be able to answer your question. But care to give us information about what microcontroller you are using, looks like an arduino from the code if I am not mistaken....?

Comment: I'm using Azure Sphere microcontroller. MT3620.

Comment: The reason I ask this is if I am not mistaken, the reason for the 2 second delay is the button check happens within the while loop, and the while loop has a bunch of other conditions that it is checking on each iteration(reason for delay). What you would want to look at is "hardware interrupt pins" for your specific device

Comment: @akib Rhast Ahhh, I see. I just checked for that and the site says it's not supported but they did link to polling so I am reading that. Thank you

Comment: I was super happy to learn about the Azure Sphere program - thanks for posting!

Comment: @SteveFriedl No problem. It's a really cool device.

Comment: If you don't want delays, don't pace your main loop with... delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code reads the button which is fast, and then immediately sets outputs and sleeps 1 second, sets an output and sleeps another second before going up to check if the button is pressed again.

You should restructure the code to check the state of the button more frequently where you're going to sleep now.

Sleep for shorter periods and check to see if the button is pressed in a loop until your total sleep time has been met or the button state changes.

Comment: Or better yet - don't sleep at all.  Use the internal clock/counter to manage bright-time periods and delays.  The CPU could be something useful while waiting for the button bounce, etc. etc.

Comment: Hmm.. I never thought of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further inspection, I found these:
[image]

The above picture is linked from [here](https://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Azure_Sphere_MT3620_Development_Kit/datasheet/MediaTek%20MT3620%20Product%20Brief.pdf) , it is the spec sheet for your microcontroller.

You want to look at the "Board Pin Map section" from this [link](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Azure_Sphere_MT3620_Development_Kit/#hardware-overview) to match it with the spec sheet of the chip itself